# Define custom route with attribute for Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to do a simple, first-step login where a user provides their employee number and are registered. I tried many different combos of passing args in the `login_path()` call and as an option in the post call.

I can't get this custom route working with controller specs:

```
post "login/:znumber" => 'users#login', format: 'json', as: :login
```

Here is a call from the controller spec that is not working:

```
post login_path(), format: :json, znumber: "z1234567"
```

Curiously, the following route spec works fine:

```
expect(:post => "/login/z1234567").to route_to("users#login", format: 'json', znumber: "z1234567")
```

Also, here's the listing when I rake routes:

```
 login POST   /login/:znumber(.:format)              users#login {:format=>"json"}
```

Comment: Curious ... if you run `rake routes`, do you see login_path as a viable URL helper? If not, you might want to add `as: :login` to the custom route.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky, that was a typo, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Assuming then that `login_path` is a valid helper, have you tried `post :login, format: :json, znumber: '1234'`?

Comment: Apologies for the second comment ... my keyboard is being a jerk :). I typically don't use `xxxx_path` in Controller specs as Rspec knows what controller I'm in ... so, I use symbols (or strings) when making `post` and other HTTP calls.

Comment: It appears it was as simple as using a symbol for the path rather than string or helper.  Thanks @craig.kaminsky!

Comment: Sweet :)! Glad it's sorted out!